# MATLAB isolate and assign variable to specific elements in matrix

Tags: matlab

I am using the Identity matrix to find an inverse of a given matrix, A. I would like to pull out just the inverse matrix after the rref function, and assign it to its own variable, but I don't know Matlab well enough to figure it out on my own. Here's my code:

```
A = [1,2,-2; 1,1,1; 0,0,1;]
I = [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 0,0,1;]

Ainv = [A,I]
rref(Ainv)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult (and very unreadable) to do it without assigning to a temporary variable. So, you can use `tmp = rref(Ainv); result = tmp(:,4:end)`. Anyway, you know you can just use `inv(A)`, right?

Comment: Yes I do know about inv(A) lol. Its for an assignment that wants me to do it a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getfield(rref(Ainv), { [1:3] [4:6] }) but inv(A), or using a temporary variable is better as mentioned in the comments.